# ADF linked service connection string update

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF dataflow to process data from CosmosDB. Is there a way to auto update the connection key in linked service when the cosmosDB keys are rotated ?

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding unfortunately it is not possible directly. What you can do is have a custom logic via azure automation or any tool to rotate the keys and push the keys to the key vault when rotated. And you can map the linked service in adf ti fetch from key vault rather than manually updating it

Comment: That would work. But we are trying to avoid keeping secrets in keyvault

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you consider authenticating using the [Data Factory Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory#managed-identity). This approach avoids having to manage any passwords or keys and is the preferred approach from a security best practice.

Comment: MSI was my plan as well. Unfortunately, dataflow do not support msi yet. It is highlighted in the same link